# networking error when sending push notifications to ios using google firebase cloud functions in js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-realtime-database

Sending push notifications using a google cloud function written in js is giving me Error code: ECONNRESET errors. I am not sure i am handling the concurrency correctly but it occasionally works but mostly i get this error on the return of each concurrent request.

Have tried practically everything and i do get warnings about nested promises but can't understand how else i can do it. The code is really quite simple. If there are any experts out there who could give me some pointers i would be eternally grateful.

```
   var deviceRef = admin.firestore().collection('devices');
    var query = deviceRef.get()
        .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            var FCM = doc.data().FCM
            if( FCM !== undefined ) {
                console.log(doc.id, '=>', FCM);
                admin.messaging().sendToDevice(FCM, payload);
            }
        });
        return;
        }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
        });
        return query;
```

In the code above 'devices' is a simple list of unique identifier for a device and has one value which is the FCM token. The code seems to fire off all the requests its just the return values that give me the ECONRESET errors. If i change it to

if( FCM === my_fcm_token) instead the code works ok so its something to do with the scaling up when sending to multiple devices as if something is timing out or not getting reset correctly.

Pls experts help if you can, i really need this to work for my app to function correctly. There is a little more code but that is basically just setting up the payload and as i say it works with one device just not multiple.

any suggestions welcome i'm hope there is someone with some idea whats up.

many many many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your function is running background activities which is anything that happens after your function has terminated. A function invocation finishes once the function returns or otherwise signals completion, such as by calling the callback argument in Node.js background functions. Any code run after graceful termination cannot access the CPU and will not make any progress.

In addition, when a subsequent invocation is executed in the same environment, your background activity resumes, interfering with the new invocation. This may lead to unexpected behavior and errors that are hard to diagnose. Accessing the network after a function terminates usually leads to connections being reset (**ECONNRESET** error code).

Background activity can often be detected in logs from individual invocations, by finding anything that is logged after the line saying that the invocation finished. Background activity can sometimes be buried deeper in the code, especially when asynchronous operations such as callbacks or timers are present. Review your code to make sure all asynchronous operations finish before you terminate the function.

Comment: thanks Andre but im still stuck how to change this, you are right the return before the send spawns a separate process (I think) because all the result come back at some point later. Are you saying I should have Node.js work sequentially for each request i.e. make it synchronous but the docs are saying you need to return or catch for every 'forEach' call so I'm totally confused how to do this. Do I need an 'await' call somewhere in here but furthermore im not sure nesting 'promises' is the right way to do it since I get an ELINT warning. Any ideas how I should change the code? thanks again